# How to set cookie Timeout less than 1 minute in Forms Authentication ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, timeout, forms-authentication

In asp.net website form authentication is used with following configuration

```
<forms loginUrl="login/" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="false" />
```

The timeout value can be set only in minutes.

How can I change timeout time to **20 seconds**?

Condition: It need to be done without compiling the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, The allowed timeout is from 1 to 35791374 & You can make changes in web.config and the changes will be reflected immediately.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1">
 </sessionState>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[image]